# Java (GUI) adding JButton multiple times?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jbutton

Im learning Java and Im creating a memory type game where you have to find two equal cards.

I have created a Window etc etc but my problem is adding multiple JButtons to it. (my cards are JButtons with icons). I have commented my code where my problem is.

```
//Get the images.
private File bildmapp = new File("bildmapp");
private File[] bilder = bildmapp.listFiles();
//My own class extending JButton
Kort[] k = new Kort[bilder.length];

for(int i = 0; i < bilder.length; i++){
        k[i] = new Kort(new ImageIcon(bilder[i].getPath()));
    }



//Later in my code:
    int sum = rows * columns;
    Kort[] temp = new Kort[sum];

            //My function to randomize.
    Verktyg.slumpOrdning(k);

            //***********************//
            //Trying to fill a array from K (which contains all cards) so my temp contains SUM cards and SUM/2 pairs
    for(int i = 0; i < sum/2; i++){
        temp[i] = k[i];
        temp[i+sum/2] = k[i];
    }


            //Problem is that i only get SUM/2 (half of the cards) cards, not the 16 (8 pairs) i would like to  add in this case
            //SYNLIGT = VISIBLE.
    for(int i = 0; i < sum; i++){
        temp[i].setStatus(Kort.Status.SYNLIGT);
        j.add(temp[i]);
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code ends up adding each `Kort` object to the container twice, since the array `temp` contains two references to each `Kort`.  When you add a `Kort` a second time, it moves to the second location. A `Component` can only appear in one place at a time.

Comment: Im not quite sure that I get it. As k[] contains all my cards, I wanted to create a new array, temp, which i fill temp/2 from K/2. Then other half of temp (temp/2) would contain the same set of cards. Ie a copy of temp/2. So this would not work or am i just writing my code wrong?

Comment: Your loop does what you describe, so it's "correct" in that sense. But you can't add a card to a container twice and expect to  get two cards in the container, any more than you can get into your car twice and expect to be your own passenger :) If you need two identical cards to appear in the container at the same time, you must create two separate but identical `Kort` objects to represent them.

Answer (score 2):

You may not add the same widget twice. You need two separate buttons (but you may use the same icon on both).

Answer (score 0):

You have to create `sum` JButton objects not `sum/2`; otherwise 2 buttons are the same and therefore only displayed once.